# How can I write a Roslyn diagnostic that considers multiple types in a solution

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a large solution for a 3-tier application (using [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/)). I should like to write a Roslyn diagnostic that will help identify some types ([DTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) that are never used as parameters for a service operation. DTOs and services are in different projects in the solution.

I see that Roslyn has many interfaces that may be implemented in order to add such diagnostics. Which is most appropriate here?

Comment: You might want to clarify your space a bit more. I'm guessing most of the Roslyn team who could answer your question have no clue what DTOs or service operations are. ;-)

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: I don't think it matters; it sounds like he just wants to analyze multiple types together (find types that aren't used in other types)

Comment: @JasonMalinowski - Fair enough: edited to bracket reference to "DTOs" to make the question a bit more generic.

Comment: At least for me, my eyes started to glaze over as soon as I hit some acronyms.

Comment: In any case, the diagnostic model we have for Roslyn right now is somewhat a per-project analysis. This is partially for performance, partly for command-line builds, where a "solution" is a figment of your imagination.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: is there maybe a way to use FindAllReferences from a diagnostic? I think that could help here, as the OP looks for a way to identify types (DTOs) that are never used in public method signatures of certain other types (service operations) within his solution. And of course I'm curious myself.. ;-)

Comment: There are two problems: one, our diagnostics system is currently built to allow diagnostics that can run on command line builds. There is no concept of "solution" from the perspective of a command line build: a solution just gives a list of projects to build, and each project in isolation only sees it's input files and references. We wanted to encourage diagnostics that can be ran everywhere, so we went for this model.

Comment: Second problem is that doing find references live is really expensive. Our diagnostics system is built to assume that we don't have to recompute the entire world on every keystroke.